# Angular - use checkboxes to display/remove layers on a Leaflet map

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, if-statement, leaflet

I'm working on Angular CLI in which I've built a Leaflet Map.
The goal is to select layers with checkboxes to display them in the map as the HTML part is showing :

```
 <div class="form-check">
 <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" (change)="testCheck($event)" name="releves">
 <label class="form-check-label">Layer 1</label>
 </div>
```

When I select "Layer1", the checkbox is checked and that runs the `testCheck($event)`.

As the Typescript part is showing, I added lines of code to display the layer on the map :

```
 testCheck(event: any){
      if (event.target.name == 'releves'){
         var releves = L.tileLayer.wms('https://URL_TO_THE_WMS', {layers: 'myLayer',format: 'image/png',transparent:true});
         if (event.target.checked === true){ 
                 if (! this.mymap.hasLayer(releves)) {
                    releves.addTo(this.mymap);
                 }
                 else if (this.mymap.hasLayer(releves)) {
                    // do nothing
                 }
            let i = 0;
            this.mymap.eachLayer(function(){ i += 1; });
            console.log('Map has', i, 'layers.');
         }
         else {
                if (this.mymap.hasLayer(releves)) {
                    console.log ("has layer 1");
                    this.mymap.removeLayer(releves);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The Layer 1 is well displayed on the map, no problem here (see `releves.addTo(this.mymap)`). But I have two problems I can't resolve :

1. When I uncheck "Layer 1" (means `event.target.name` is not `true` in the **else condition part**), the layer is not removed whereas I use the `removeLayer` method.
2. The `hasLayer` method does not seem to work. Indeed after having displayed the layer 1, when I uncheck and test if the layer is present, I should get the console.log message `"has layer 1"` before the removal. But there's nothing...

May you know how to debug that ?
Any help would be very appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create a brand new `releves` layer everytime the `testCheck` method is called, so `hasLayer(releves)` will always be `false`.

Store your layer in a "permanent" state, typically as a member of your Angular component, exactly like you do for `mymap`:

```
@Component({})
export class MyComponent {
  releves = L.tileLayer.wms();

  testCheck(event) {
    if (this.mymap.hasLayer(this.releves)) {
      // etc.
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Great thank you very much @ghybs ! Just tried it and that works well. I gave it many tries but didn't think to use the WMS as a permanent variable, my bad